# AngularJS temporarily disable animations

Tags: css, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I have a pretty complex `ng-repeat`. The number of displayed items can be controlled by two buttons. The **first button** removes a single element from the ng-repeat by using a filter. The **second button** removes a bunch of elements and displays a bunch of other elements (also by using a filter).

I currently have an animation on the ng-repeat like this:

```
<style>
   .animation {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
  }
  .animation.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   /* Similar for ng-leave */
</style>

<div class="animation" data-ng-repeat="item in items"> ... </div>
```

When the user clicks the first button I want the elements to use the animation. 
When the user clicks the second button I want to disable any animations.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ng-class` directive to have `animation` class conditionally. Remove `animation` class when you don't want it, specifically saying on click of second button.

```
<div ng-class="{animation: expression }" data-ng-repeat="item in items"> ... </div>
```

In above snippet `expression` will be condition/scope variable which will set to `false` so that `animation` will get removed and animation will get disabled.

Comment: I think that if the function is doing more stuff in the controller, it should first set the `expression` to false, and then put the rest of the code inside a `$timeout` (or something like that) to allow the view to render and remove the `animation` class

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you, the timeout was necessary indeed!